# SP list Calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

Trying to do calculated column where if the column text length is equal to 176 characters column returns 1, if not 0.

Using this formula:

```
=LEN([AZDP]=176, "1", "0")
```

This is returning error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring column settings as below:

[image]

Return data type as **Number**.

**Formula used**:

```
=IF(LEN([AZDP]) = 176, 1, 0)
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Notes**:

1. **Multiple lines of text** column are not supported in calculated column formula
2. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try as following:

```
IF(LEN([AZDP])=176, "1", "0")
```

More inforamtion:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a

Comment: Hi Julie, it is returning true all the time :(
This is the text formula is looking at:

["Maintain a safe distance from moving rail vehicles","Maintain a safe distance from lifting operations","Check the absence of voltage before working on electrical parts","One person, one lock, one key"]

Comment: What is the column type of AZDP? What is the text formula you provided?

Comment: It is text. 

The text input reads: 

 ["Maintain a safe distance from moving rail vehicles","Maintain a safe distance from lifting operations","Check the absence of voltage before working on electrical parts","One person, one lock, one key"]